# Make clearRect() of canvas work faster

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to design a traveling sine wave in JavaScript, but the design appears quite slow. The main bottleneck is the `clearRect()` for canvas clearing.

How can I solve this?

Also I am drawing the pixel by `ctx.fillRect(x, y,1,1)`, but when I clear using `clearRect(x, y,1,1)`, it leaves some footprints. Instead I have to do `clearRect(x, y,5,5)` to get proper clearing. What can be the work around?

```
/******************************/

var x = 0;
var sineval = [];
var offset = 0;
var animFlag;

function init() {

    for(var i=0; i<=1000; ++i){
        sineval[i] = Math.sin(i*Math.PI/180);   
    }
    // Call the sineWave() function repeatedly every 1 microseconds
    animFlag = setInterval(sineWave, 1);
    //sineWave();
}


function sineWave()
{   //console.log('Drawing Sine');

    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

    if (canvas.getContext) {
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    }

    for(x=0 ; x<1000 ;++x){

        // Find the sine of the angle
        //var i = x % 361;
        var y = sineval[x+offset];

        // If the sine value is positive, map it above y = 100 and change the colour to blue
        if(y >= 0)
        {
            y = 100 - (y-0) * 70;
            ctx.fillStyle = "green";
        }

        // If the sine value is negative, map it below y = 100 and change the colour to red
        if( y < 0 )
        {
            y = 100 + (0-y) * 70;
            ctx.fillStyle = "green";
        }

        // We will use the fillRect method to draw the actual wave. The length and breath of the
        if(x == 0) ctx.clearRect(0,y-1,5,5);
        else ctx.clearRect(x,y,5,5);
        ctx.fillRect(x, y,1,1 /*Math.sin(x * Math.PI/180) * 5, Math.sin(x * Math.PI/180 * 5)*/);

    }

    offset = (offset > 360) ? 0 : ++offset ;
}
```

Comment: Why are you clearing single points at all? Just clear the whole canvas before each redraw.

Comment: I did try that but it gives flickering effect.

Comment: As Bergi says, clear the whole canvas. Also, don't set a timer below 16ms (yours is 1ms) because the browser won't refresh the display faster than 16ms. And since your sine wave is invariant, consider pre-rendering an image of your sine wave and "animate" that image across the canvas by changing it's X coordinate during each frame.

Comment: the sine wave is variant...it has amplitude and frequency controls

Comment: Note that the green,red comment is not implemented in code. The two formulas for the y are identical, each is just y=-70y+100. As others have said instead of re-sizing the [-1,1] range sine data to [30,170] every frame, just do it at init time and save that enlarged range inside the sinewave array. Instead of using fill and clear, manipulate the pixels directly. Use context.getImageData or context.createImageData (pick) once at init and then manipulate the .data array of the returned object with pixel values you want for the frame. at end of frame use context.putImageData.

Answer (score 3):

You need to refactor the code a bit:

- Move all global variables such as canvas and context outside of the loop function
- Inside the loop, clear full canvas at beginning, redraw sine
- Use `requestAnimationFrame` instead of `setInterval`
- Replace `fillRect()` with `rect()` and do a single `fill()` outside the inner for-loop

Using a timeout value of 1 ms will potentially result in blocking the browser, or at least slow it down noticeably. Considering that a monitor update only happens every 16.7ms this will of course be wasted cycles. If you want to reduce/increase the speed of the sine you can reduce/increase the incremental step instead.

In essence:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var sineval = [];
var offset = 0;

init();

function init() {

  for (var i = 0; i <= 1000; ++i) {
    sineval.push(Math.sin(i * Math.PI / 180));
  }

  // Call the sineWave() function
  sineWave();
}


function sineWave() {

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.fillStyle = "green";

  // draw positive part of sine wave here
  for (var x = 0; x < 1000; x++) {
    var y = sineval[x + offset];
    if (y >= 0) {
      y = 100 - (y - 0) * 70;
      ctx.rect(x, y, 2, 2);
    }
  }

  ctx.fill();

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.fillStyle = "red";

  // draw negative part of sine wave here
  for (var x = 0; x < 1000; x++) {
    var y = sineval[x + offset];
    if (y < 0) {
      y = 100 - (y - 0) * 70;
      ctx.rect(x, y, 2, 2);
    }
  }
  ctx.fill();

  offset = (offset > 360) ? 0 : ++offset;
  
  requestAnimationFrame(sineWave);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=800 height=500></canvas>
```

And of course, if you load the script in `<head>` you need to wrap it in a `window.onload` block so canvas element is available. Or simply place the script at the bottom of the page if you haven't already.

Comment: I did as you said but it improved the speed only marginally.

Comment: @AbhinavMishra there there is nothing in your code which should indicate it would be a performance problem. Could you set up a working fiddle/inline example so we can look closer at it?

Comment: @AbhinavMishra I'll actually take that back... Looking at the way it is plotted there are 1000 fills happening each frame. I rewrote your plotting method to only add to the path and do a single fill outside that loop. See if that helps.

Comment: @AbhinavMishra I get 60 fps in both FF and in Chrome, which is fine (you need to do performance test to find out how much of the time slice is actually used though). But I cannot see any particular problem with the code (no flickering)? Is the computer you're at hardware accelerated (gpu)? If you tried my updated example code, how does that perform on your setup? BTW, by "flickering", do you mean flashing or uneven movement?

Comment: I have i5 processor and in my mozilla browser,the wave motion is kinda discrete but the output at jsfiddle seems fine to me too.       BTW, if I want to increase the speed of the wave how can i do that?

Comment: @AbhinavMishra I would not cache the values in an array (init()), but do the math directly inside the loop (but using radians instead of degrees). This way you can simply increase the frequency parameter and everything will follow automatically. The performance cost is low.

Comment: Is extracting a stored value more expensive(in terms of speed) than calculating the intensive Math operations? Also the sine values of a period is same. Doesn't it make more logic to store in an array and just multiply by amplitude factors?

Comment: @AbhinavMishra (updated comment) caching the values is faster over-all but it's not necessary needed in a scenario where frame rate controls the update. If you are on a tight performance budget it could matter - it's not much extra code so it depends on wanted flexibility (the cache needs to be updated if input parameters changes). The real cost is the polygon filling. You want to avoid too many fill operations, so first adding all rectangles to the path, then fill once is much faster.

Comment: @KenFrystenberg Can you show me how can I do the drawing on canvas in a single fill outside the loop.

Comment: I am new to jsfiddle. How can I look your answer?

Comment: @AbhinavMishrajust just click the "Run code snippet" button. Is there not one on your page? If not, the complete source is listed in the answer (below "in essence:"). If you don't see it there must be something wrong with SO at the moment.

Comment: can you send me your jsfiddle link?

Answer (score 0):

A few speedups and odd ends:

- In init, set up the sine wave pixel values one time.
- Use typed arrays for these since sticking with integers is faster than using floats if possible.
- We will manipulate the pixel data directly instead of using fill and clear. To start this, in init we call ctx.getImageData one time. We also just one time max the alpha value of all the pixels since the default 0 value is transparent and we want full opacity at 255.
- Use setInterval like before. We want to update the pixels at a steady rate.
- Use 'adj' as knob to adjust how fast the sine wave moves on the screen. The actual value (a decimal) will depend on the drawing frame rate. We use Date.now() calls to keep track of milliseconds consumed across frames. So the adjustment on the millisecond is mod 360 to set the 'offset' variable. Thus offset value is not inc by 1 every frame but instead is decided based on the consumption of time. The adj value could later be connected to gui if want.
- At end of work (in sineWave function), we call requestAnimationFrame simply to do the ctx.putImageData to the canvas,screen in sync to avoid tearing. Notice 'paintit' function is fast and simple. Notice also that we still require setInterval to keep steady pace.
- In between setting the offset and calling requestAnimationFrame, we do two loops. The first efficiently blackens out the exact pixels we drew from the prior frame (sets to 0). The second loop draws the new sine wave. Top half of wave is green (set the G in pixel rgba to 255). Bottom half is red (set the R pixel rgba to 255).
- Use the .data array to paint a pixel, and index it to the pixel using 4*x + 4*y*canvas.width. Add 1 more if want the green value instead of the red one. No need to touch the blue value (byte offset 2) nor the already set alpha (byte offset 3).
- The >>>0 used in some places turns the affected value into an unsigned integer if it wasn't already. It can also be used instead of Math.ceil. .data is typed Array already I think.
- This answer is rather late but it addresses some issues brought up in comments or otherwise not yet addressed. The question showed up during googling.
- Code hasn't been profiled. It's possible some of the speedups didn't speed anything up; however, the cpu consumption of firefox was pretty light by the end of the adjustments. It's set to run at 40 fps. Make 'delay' smaller to speed it up and tax cpu more.

```js
var sineval;
var offset = 0;
var animFlag;
var canvas;
var ctx;
var obj;
var milli;
var delay=25;
var adj=1/delay;  // .04 or so for 25 delay

function init() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    obj=ctx.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

    for (let i=0; i<obj.data.length; i+=4) {
        obj.data[i+3]=255;  //set all alpha to full one time only needed.
    }

    sineval=new Uint8Array(1400);  //set up byte based table of final pixel sine values.. 1400 degrees total
    for (let i=0; i<=1400; ++i) {  //1400
        sineval[i] = (100-70*Math.sin(i*Math.PI/180))>>>0;   
    }

    animFlag = setInterval(sineWave, delay);  //do processing once every 25 milli

    milli=Date.now()>>>0;   //start time in milli
}

function sineWave() {
    let m=((Date.now()-milli)*adj)>>>0;
    let oldoff = offset;
    offset=(m % 360)>>>0;     //offset,frequency tuned with adj param.
    
    for(x=0 ; x<1000 ;++x) {  //draw sine wave across canvas length of 1000
        let y=sineval[x+oldoff];
        obj.data [0+x*4+y*4*canvas.width]=0; //black the reds
        obj.data [1+x*4+y*4*canvas.width]=0; //black the greens
    }

    for(x=0 ; x<1000 ;++x) {  //draw sine wave across canvas length of 1000
        let y=sineval[x+offset];
        if (y<100) {
            obj.data [1+x*4+y*4*canvas.width]=255; //rGba  //green for top half
        } else {
            obj.data [0+x*4+y*4*canvas.width]=255; //Rgba  //red for bottom half
        }
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(paintit);   //at end of processing try to paint next frame boundary
}

function paintit() {
    ctx.putImageData(obj,0,0);
}

init();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" height=300 width=1000></canvas>
```